# Spell checking in PyQtWebEngine

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I am writing a program which is mainly in python but some interactive features are done through a web-app that talks to flask. It would be nice to have the web-app inside the python program so I am looking at using PyQtWebEngine.

This works surprisingly well except that I cannot get spell checking to work. I have run

```
self.page().profile().setSpellCheckEnabled(True)
self.page().profile().setSpellCheckLanguages({"en-GB"})
```

from inside my child class of `QWebEngineView`, and I have checked `isSpellCheckEnabled()` is True.

I wonder if it cannot find the languages. No qWarning is detected which I would expect if it cannot find the dictionary. As suggested by the [non-python example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-spellchecker-example.html).

I have an `en-GB.bdic` which I copied from the Chromium hunspell git. I have tried putting the file at:

```
<directory_my_py_file_is_in>/qtwebengine_dictionaries/en-GB.bdic
```

When I run

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
print(app.applicationDirPath())
```

the result is

```
/usr/bin
```

so I tried

```
/usr/bin/qtwebengine_dictionaries/en-GB.bdic
```

This wouldn't have been OK because I cannot edit this location when the program is pip installed, but it was worth a try.

With the `.bdic` file in either place I never see any spell check feature.

Has anyone got spellchecking working in PyQtWebEngine? I have not been able to find much in the way of documentation.

Comment: What is your OS and how have you installed PyQtWebEngine?

Comment: Yes the PyQtWebEngine is installed with pip. The web engine is working fine, it is just the spell checker that doesn't. OS is Kubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the .bdic are valid then I have established the path of the dictionaries through the environment variable `QTWEBENGINE_DICTIONARIES_PATH`, for example I have translated the official example into python with the following structure:

```
├── data
│   ├── icon.svg
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── spellchecker.qrc
│   └── style.css
├── dict
│   ├── de
│   │   ├── de-DE.aff
│   │   ├── de-DE.dic
│   │   └── README.txt
│   └── en
│       ├── en-US.aff
│       ├── en-US.dic
│       └── README.txt
├── main.py
├── spellchecker_rc.py
├── qtwebengine_dictionaries
│   ├── de-DE.bdic
│   └── en-US.bdic
└── README.md
```

**main.py**

```py
# ...
CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
os.environ["QTWEBENGINE_DICTIONARIES_PATH"] = os.path.join(
    CURRENT_DIR, "qtwebengine_dictionaries"
)
# ...
```

**Note:** To get the bdic I have used the qwebengine_convert_dict tool executing:

```
qwebengine_convert_dict dict/en/en-US.dic qtwebengine_dictionaries/en-US.bdic
qwebengine_convert_dict dict/de/de-DE.dic qtwebengine_dictionaries/de-DE.bdic
```

<sub>The complete code is [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/QtExamples/tree/master/official/webenginewidgets/spellchecker).</sub>

Comment: Your examples repository is fantastic. The environment variable did the trick after I looked at your code and saw some other mistakes I made converting over to PyQT5. Most importantly `self.page().profile().setSpellCheckLanguages({"en-GB"})` should have been self.page().profile().setSpellCheckLanguages(("en-GB",))`