QtWebEngineWidgets searching wrong directory?
Trying to do a basic program utilizing QWebEngineView:
from PyQt6.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):  
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.google.com"))

        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()

app.exec

And getting the following response:
Path override failed for key base::DIR_APP_DICTIONARIES and path '/home/serveracct/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/bin/qtwebengine_dictionaries'
Path override failed for key base::DIR_APP_DICTIONARIES and path '/home/serveracct/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt6/Qt6/libexec/qtwebengine_dictionaries'
Path override failed for key base::DIR_APP_DICTIONARIES and path '/home/serveracct/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt6/Qt6/libexec/qtwebengine_dictionaries'

When I checked the aforementioned directories, I couldn't find qtwebengine_dictionaries in
serveracct@heisenberg:~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/bin$

And as far as the last two, I found:
serveracct@heisenberg:~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt6/Qt6/libexec/QtWebEngineProcess

Debian 12/Python 3.9 using pyenv and the following libraries installed:
Package                     Version
--------------------------- -------
pip                         24.2
PyQt6                       6.7.1
PyQt6-Qt6                   6.7.2
PyQt6_sip                   13.8.0
PyQt6-WebEngine             6.7.0
PyQt6-WebEngine-Qt6         6.7.2
PyQt6-WebEngineSubwheel-Qt6 6.7.2
setuptools                  49.2.1

I tried downgrading to PyQt6 6.6.0/PyQt6-WebEngine 6.6.0 same issue

Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61987930/spell-checking-in-pyqtwebengine

@eyllanesc....setting environmental variable for QTWEBENGINE_DICTIONARIES_PATH worked...thank you!
